# Combine data and Join certain column between two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I hv two tables which are tbl_product1 and tbl_product2.

**tbl_product1 :**

```
model_name
lot_num
status_prod1
datecreated
date_received
```

**tbl_product2:**

```
model_name
lot_num
status_prod2
last_date
```

I want to combine model_name between this two table and lot_num as well in one column. Then join status_prod1, datecreated, date_received from tbl_prod1 and status_prod2, last_date.

**My sql query :**

```
 $query = "SELECT c.model_name, c.lot_num, c.s1, c.s2, c.datecreated, c.date_received, c.last_date
              FROM (SELECT model_name, lot_num, status_prod1 AS s1, NOT NULL AS s2, datecreated, date_received,  NULL AS last_date FROM tbl_product1 WHERE status_prod1 = 'sent' UNION SELECT model_name, lot_num, NOT NULL AS s1, status_prod2 AS s2, NULL AS datecreated, NULL AS date_received, last_date  FROM tbl_product2 WHERE status_prod2 = 'sent')c
    ORDER BY model_name, lot_num ASC";
```

But the result is not as my expectation. When I run this query, it display double lot_num and model_name. I dont know how to explain.

For example when i running my code this output will display :

```
model_name | lot_num | status_prod1 | status_prod2
---------------------------------------------------
magic1     | 001     | sent         | 
magic1     | 001     |              |  sent
sss        | 100     | sent         |
ddd        | 222     | sent         |
ddd        | 222     |              |  sent
```

**Supposely the table should like this :**

```
model_name | lot_num | status_prod1 | status_prod2
---------------------------------------------------
magic1     | 001     | sent         | sent
sss        | 100     | sent         |
ddd        | 222     | sent         | sent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get what you want with aggregation:

```
SELECT c.model_name, c.lot_num,
       max(c.s1) as s1, max(c.s2) as s2, max(c.datecreated) as date_created,
       max(c.date_received) as date_received, max(c.last_date)
FROM (SELECT model_name, lot_num, status_prod1 AS s1, NOT NULL AS s2, datecreated, date_received,  NULL AS last_date
      FROM tbl_product1
      WHERE status_prod1 = 'sent' UNION ALL
      SELECT model_name, lot_num, NOT NULL AS s1, status_prod2 AS s2, NULL AS datecreated, NULL AS date_received, last_date 
      FROM tbl_product2
      WHERE status_prod2 = 'sent'
     ) c
GROUP BY c.model_name, c.lot_num
ORDER BY model_name, lot_num ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just those 7 columns, a simple `INNER JOIN` will be okay. Inner joins will only return rows that have model_name's and lot_num's which are present in both tables:

*(UNTESTED)*

```
SELECT 
  a.model_name, a.lot_num, a.status_prod1, a.datecreated, a.date_received
  b.status_prod2, b.last_date
FROM
  tbl_product1 a 
INNER JOIN 
  tbl_product2 b 
ON
  a.model_name = b.model_name AND a.lot_num = b.lot_num
WHERE
  b.status_prod2 = 'sent' OR a.status_prod1 = 'sent'
ORDER BY 
  a.model_name, a.lot_num ASC;
```

Comment: I run your code but it just retrieve model_name and lot_num if status_prod1 and status_prod2 are sent. I want to include if either one of status is sent also. @Scopey

Comment: Does my edit solve your issue? I just added an "`OR a.status_prod1 = 'sent'`" in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Sceopey It is the status will retrieve based on model_name and lot_num exists on tbl_prod1 only? Thats why I use union to combine all model_name and lot_num between these two table. But I dont know how to use. Pls help me